# SQL Misinterpretation of Return in IF Scope Context

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to script a new database and have a valid scaler function script for one operation. Being a good script writer, I want to check to see if the function exists before attempting to do the `Create Function`, but I get this error when I combine the two:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FUNCTION'.
> ...
> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

How can both be accomplished?

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    where Specific_schema = 'util'
    AND   specific_name   = 'TableState_Boolean'
    AND   ROUTINE_TYPE    = 'FUNCTION')
BEGIN
    create FUNCTION util.TableState_Boolean()
    RETURNS tinyint
    as BEGIN return 1; END    
end
```

Comment: Side point: scalar functions are a major performance issue, and should generally be avoided. Use *inine* Table Valued Functions instead. Also, for a boolean value you can use the `bit` data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CREATE FUNCTION must be the first statement in a query batch, so use dynamic SQL, eg

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    where Specific_schema = 'util'
    AND   specific_name   = 'TableState_Boolean'
    AND   ROUTINE_TYPE    = 'FUNCTION')
BEGIN
    exec('
    create FUNCTION util.TableState_Boolean()
    RETURNS tinyint
    as BEGIN return 1; END    
    ')
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `CREATE OR ALTER` to create the `Funcation` in sql-server

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION util.TableState_Boolean()
RETURNS tinyint
AS BEGIN 
    return 1; 
END;
```

Comment: Even though I marked the other post as the answer, the logic of the *overwrite* instead of checking for existence does make sense and I may use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try in two steps like first drop existsing UDF and then create a new one like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('util.TableState_Boolean') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION util.TableState_Boolean
GO

CREATE FUNCTION util.TableState_Boolean ...
GO
```

. . . or the other way around -- first create an empty "stub" UDF if it does not exist and then ALTER it with its new definition although in this case you'll have to use dynamic SQL too.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('util.TableState_Boolean') IS NULL EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TableState_Boolean() RETURNS tinyint AS BEGIN RETURN NULL END'
GO

ALTER FUNCTION util.TableState_Boolean ...
GO
```

Btw, `CREATE OR ALTER` is introduced in SQL 2016 and is not available in previous versions.